# Jquery Check for selected option ignoring one option

Tags: jquery

I have an page with a selection box, the first option of which is please choose, I need to ensure the user has made a selection ignoring the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.selectedIndex` (faster) or [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for this:

```
if($("#selectID")[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
  alert("Please choose something");
}
//or no jQuery at all:
if(document.getElementById("selectID").selectedIndex == 0) {
```

Or the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the selected `<option>`, much slower but works:

```
if($("#selectID :selected").index() == 0) {
  alert("Please choose something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the first option a value "0":

```
<select id="#myselectionbox">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    ...
</select>
```

and check the selected value:

```
if ($("#myselectionbox").val() != "0") {
   // ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
if ($("#yourselectid").val() == "Please ignore") {
  alert("You must select another option.");
}
```